# Subsequently adding elements to an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a listOfStrings, and I want to create a new listOfStringsTwo (both lists are ArrayLists) where each element is concatenated on to the next one progressively. Here is an example:

If the original listOfStrings had elements "hi", "hello" and "bye", the listOfStringsTwo would have the following as its elements:

```
listOfStringsTwo.get(o) would give "hi"
listOfStringsTwo.get(1) would give "hi" "hello"
listOfStringsTwo.get(2) would give "hi" "hello" "bye"
```

I feel as though I need to use a for loop but I am very unsure of how to proceed. I've looked at the Java docs and countless tutorials but I'm still stuck on this seemingly simple problem.

---

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please, if my question is of the wrong type or if there are any problems with it, please do let me know! I am learning Java by myself and am stuck on a neat situation.

Comment: have you consider to call sublist on your list?

Comment: Btw, are you using any text book, video tutorial or college course to learn ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a textbook in Farsi. Its not available online unfortunately but its in my native tongue. Is there a different way of going about this problem without sublist? More manually per se?

Comment: You wrote about concatenation, but this '"hi" "hello" "bye"' seems hardly concatenated - looks as if you wanted to return N elemenents. Did you mean to write: "hi hello bye"?

Comment: Yes my apologies, that is what I meant!

Comment: @nicefella: Welcome! For best results, don't open a question with irrelevant information. Open with a clear, concise statement of the question. This is what appears on the question list, and will be what gets people to click through to try to help you. (In general, it's best to leave off the meta content entirely, but I just moved it to the end.)

Comment: Will do@T.J.Crowder, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @nicefella: Also, don't put tags in the title, just use tags and the system will handle it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: See bottom of my answer for an update.

if I understood what you want to achieve, then here is the situation:

```
  original.get(0) gives "hi"
  original.get(1) gives "hello"
  original.get(2) gives "bye"
```

and you want to have a second list that copies items from original but in a cumulative way:

```
  seocnd.get(0) gives "hi"
  seocnd.get(1) gives "hi hello"
  seocnd.get(2) gives "hi hello bye"
```

The here is one way to do so:

```
List<String> originalList = new List<String>();

originalList.add("hi");
originalList.add("hello");
originalList.add("bye");

List<String> listofStringsTwo = new List<String>();

for (int i=0; i<original.size ; i++)
{
  String temp = "";
  for (int j=0;j<=i;j++)
  {
    temp += original.get(j) + " ";
  }
  listofStringsTwo.add( temp );
}
```

UPDATE: If you need to include a fourth element to the list, then just add it normally to the original. It will be appended to the fourth element of the second list automatically, without you having to adjust the code below it.

```
originalList.add("hi");
originalList.add("hello");
originalList.add("bye");
originalList.add("goodbye");
```

Comment: Quick follow up question, how would be method change if I just wanted to add a string, say "goodbye" at the very end iteration? @Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

runtime complexity O(n)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfStrings.add("hi");
    listOfStrings.add("hello");
    listOfStrings.add("bye");

    List<String> listOfStringsTwo = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String str: listOfStrings) {
        sb.append(str).append(" ");
        listOfStringsTwo.add(sb.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(listOfStringsTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 choices (I think that you should extend existing ArrayList class - for the start):

1. More memory expensive, but faster access to N-th element

This one will be more memory expensive as your list would always store all concatenated entries but would also give you faster access.

When adding new element to the end of the list just get N-1 element and concatenate it with the new value (N-1 will always contain all previous words) and store it at the end.

2. More time consuming on "get" method, but easier on memory

Override "get(int index)" method, and perform entire concatenation there - more less like Ahmad wrote before.

For small values of N both solutions will work almost identically.